# How can I get an UIImageView's graphic context?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a **UIImageView**.

I would like to get it's context so that I can draw ontop of it.

I understand I can get my main graphic context by calling `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`, but I would like to draw on my image view, not the background of the form.  Is this possible, and if so how?

I attempted to draw to the main UI graphics context, but nothing appeared.  I assume it is drawing under my image views.  Am I correct or am I confused in this context?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're a little confused. :) The view doesn't *have* a context. When the view is about to be painted on the screen, UIKit sets up a graphics context, gives it to the view, and calls the view's `drawRect:`. The view can then put drawing instructions into the context. Once the view is done, UIKit whisks the context away and turns the drawing instructions into a bitmap, which it puts on the screen.

So the view only has access to a graphics context that's going to the screen when UIKit sets it up. In order for *you* to get access to this context, you have to put code inside the view's `drawRect:`. You can't actually draw into an arbitrary view on the screen.

What you can do is put your own, mostly-transparent view on top of it and draw into that.